# Restoring a database to a point in time: Database I want not showing up in dropdown list

Tags: sql-server-2008, restore

I want to restore to a point in time from a database that is already attached.  When I try to do this using SMSS I cannot find the database I want in the dropdown list, but oddly it has a couple databases in the list that have been deleted.

I tried closing/reopening SMSS in hopes that it would refresh but no such luck.

Anyone know why the database is not showing up in the "From database:" drop down list?

EDIT:

If I try to restore a backup to a point in time then no backup sets appear for me to select.  However, if I restore the backup to the most recent point in time and then restore the transaction log then I'm able to select a point in time when restoring the transaction log.  But then when I query the database I find that it's still restored to the most recent point in time from the database backup rather than the time I selected for the transaction log.

How do I restore to a point in time?  The backups are using the full backup model, but I'm not sure if I should be doing anything else as part of the backup to be able to restore to a point in time.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What drop down are you referring to?

Comment: In Management Studio when you restore a database you have the option to restore from a database or from a device.  The dropdown for restoring from a database is the one I'm referring to.

Comment: Do you have permissions to restore a database?